# Are questions about proprietary file formats allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have run into trouble decoding a certain [kind of file from a commercial game](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/PHY). The file format is only partially documented online. The information I need is listed as "To do" on the website (owned by the company) so presumably they're alright with it being public.

Still, to make sure; is it okay? I know some people might see it as cracking a code; others as deducing a format.

Comment: Can you make an example?

Comment: It's about this format: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/PHY

Comment: Can you post the specific question you want to ask? I can think of plenty of questions about the format that would be on-topic, but also plenty that would be off-topic.

Comment: In general, its about a public facing API, so I don't see any reason you couldn't ask (apart from general question quality of course)

Comment: It would be something like "Hello, I'm researching game collisions, I'm using .phy as a model to understand collision meshes, and I want to extract the collision mesh from a .phy file. However it is only partially documented in this link. The "to do" part detailing what is in the collision data is missing. I have however deduced the vertices are between these offsets and blah blah and I think the triangles are here but they have strange values."

Comment: I do not think this would be on topic. It is essentially work you need to do yourself, and also it may not be entirely moral to do. Asking this question would probably not be well received on main.

Comment: It looks like he's doing a lot of work already. I'd give it a try (of course I can't guarantee success.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Sure, he has done a lot of tangential work already. But ripping out some logic from a published game's compiled code seems to be like a lot of work. It requires *a lot* of work actually, and there is nothing trivial about the process.

Comment: @TravisJ Why do you assume that the only way to get this information is to look at compiled game code?

Comment: @Kyle - That generally is what "decode" means. *I have run into trouble decoding a certain kind of file from a commercial game*.

Comment: I really mean "decode" as "understand".

Comment: @TravisJ: No, that's what "decompile" means...

Comment: proprietary file types are the devil's work...

Comment: @bombax are you working on open morrowind ?

Answer (score 30):

What you have to be careful about is not falling afoul of the following close reason:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

If you do not make it really clear that you are **asking a specific answerable problem** and not sounding like you are looking for a third party resource you might get some help.

I think you should be able to show what you have done and why you think the data that is not documented is *strange* you might have a pretty good question.

Answer (score 27):

I think this site tries in good faith to presume an innocent state of mind for most posters; that is, the assumption is that most questions here aren't related to some nefarious, evil underlying purpose. On that basis, if someone wants to know about a file format, the preferred assumption is that the person isn't necessarily trying to hack something or do something malevolent. As a result, I think those questions should *generally* be allowed.

Comment: And then you get a guy who asks "How can I crack this password stored in MySQL" and you just _know_ something's up.

Answer (score 4):

I see mostly the copyright issue here.

Your question including code snippets will be under creative commons (cc by-sa 3.0). So in case you post content that is incompatible with this license you might run into problems. Anyway you could still link to it, describe it another way, etc.. I'm not a lawyer but one has to be careful.

Make sure your question about proprietary file formats can be published under cc by-sa 3.0.

All the other typical close reasons (asking for recommendations, unclear what is asked, asking for opinions) can be circumvented in the normal way.

Questions about proprietary file formats may tend to be very specific and only for marginal interest. But this is not a close reason.