# Should SO Documentation be used for documenting file formats?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Is it worthwhile documenting common file formats? What about proprietary file formats?

In the case of the former, there is an issue of redundancy since detailed specifications will probably be available elsewhere. In the second case, where crowd-sourced documentation of reverse-engineered file formats would most useful, is there an issue with copyright?

Obviously, cutting and pasting copyrighted file format documentation is a problem, but what about original documentation explaining copyrighted file formats (e.g. Autodesk .bip format)?

[Related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294634/are-questions-about-proprietary-file-formats-allowed) about proprietary file formats and Q&A.

Comment: Are we talking about common file formats (like .OBJ mesh files or .TGA images) or [really](https://gitlab.com/gobusto/loadgamemesh/blob/d2604f41cbc53f6c9ac4e25aa0fdd6cd64671788/docs/rfc_format.md) [obscure](https://gitlab.com/gobusto/loadgamemesh/blob/85fa7495db2a3bc05c62178706139d1f85e8e267/docs/rfl_format.md) ones? In the former case, good documentation already exists elsewhere; in the latter, I doubt that there'd be enough users interested in specific oddball formats to make it worthwhile.

Answer (score 32):

Understanding and implementing file formats is a fairly common programming task and there exist tags for common file formats like TIFF, HDF, .. in the Q&A part of Stack Overflow. I don't see why you cannot have documentation of file formats on Stack Overflow Documentation then if the following points are taken into account.

- Don't duplicate good documentation that is available elsewhere. Common file formats are usually well documented, however, stuff that goes beyond (examples, tips and tricks) would probably be useful.
- Always respect copyright. Only publish material here that can be licensed under the Stack Overflow license.
- Be aware that you need currently five people with experience in a tag on Q&A Stack Overflow to also create a tag on Documentation. This might severely limit tags about file formats.
- Topic proposals may be rejected as not needed. It may be seen as too specific to be of interest. This might limit topic creation about file formats.
- The good thing is that the scope of topics on Documentation can be broader than that of a question in the Q&A part of Stack Overflow.
- Finally, while documenting file formats is programming related, Documentation is also very example centric. I wonder if the current structure of a topic page really fits the needs of documenting file formats well? It might be Documentation is not the best way to document file formats, except if you have many good examples.

Comment: This is a great answer to the question: "Under the current format and understanding of DocsSO, how does one document file formats?" Thank you for the good and complete answer. But that wasn't the question. That may have been the intended question, though, perhaps the OP needs to edit the question to fit this answer? Or perhaps this answer reflects an implied 'yes, of course'?

Comment: @CWilson Many thanks for the comment. It's a "Yes", but with restrictions. I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I wouldn't say *Don't duplicate good documentation that is available elsewhere* . That might throw the whole concept of Docs away.

Comment: Well, @Drew, that is explicitly not the mission of Docs. The team has said from the beginning that they don't want Docs to turn into a copy of MSDN, MDN, jQuery, or whatever other official documentation. The only things we should be documenting are those things that *aren't* well documented elsewhere. Granted, *most* of the libraries/APIs that I use are already well-documented (perhaps that's why I use them?), so it does kind of make Docs seem superfluous, but the only thing worse than a superfluous feature is an actively harmful one that fragments content and risks misleading programmers.

Comment: @Drew The "Don't duplicate good content" is the official line and also the fragmentation issue was one of the most often raiseed objection when the proposal for Documentation was made ([Warlords of Documentation: A Proposed Expansion of Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303867/1536976)). Some sort of duplication is probably unavoidable, but Docs only makes much sense in my opinion if a) it finds its niche, and b) it offers better service.

Comment: @CodyGray if it is "explicitly not the mission" does that mean that is should be frowned upon or a reason to delete? I imagine that 60 to 80 percent of what I have put together is easily obtained elsewhere and the same for every example I have seen in Docs/mysql. I spent at least 20 minutes putting [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/4137/data-types/18480) together mainly due to the first time with a table markup. Alright, 30 to 40 minutes. The whole time wondering how silly. Sure, 1 stop shopping and links. But what is the point of it?

Comment: Somewhat ironically, @Drew, you didn't actually use [the table markup](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables). As for your actual question about whether duplicated content should be "frowned up" or deleted outright, I'd say that's still up in the air. The team hasn't been exactly forthcoming with guidance, but it has been pretty clear from the beginning that, as I said, the purpose of Documentation is not to duplicate things that are already well-documented elsewhere. Then again, if you really think you're adding something useful to the body of knowledge on the Internet, then go for it.

Comment: I searched for markup, found a meta. I will try to improve it if I stumbled into the wrong one after the 10 minutes I searched. Probably.